# Protractor clear() not working

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have two tests:

```
  it('should filter the phone list as user types into the search box', function() {

    var results = ptor.findElements(protractor.By.repeater('phone in phones').column('phone.name'));
    results.then(function(arr) {
            expect(arr.length).toEqual(3);
    });

    var queryInput = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.input('query'));

    queryInput.sendKeys('nexus');

    results = ptor.findElements(protractor.By.repeater('phone in phones').column('phone.name'));
    results.then(function(arr) {
        expect(arr.length).toEqual(1);
    });

    queryInput.clear();
    queryInput.sendKeys('motorola');

    results = ptor.findElements(protractor.By.repeater('phone in phones').column('phone.name'));
    results.then(function(arr) {
        expect(arr.length).toEqual(2);
    });

});

it('should display the current filter value within an element with id "status"',
    function() {
        //expect(element('#status').text()).toMatch(/Current filter: \s*$/);
        var queryInput = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.input('query'));
        queryInput.clear();

        expect(ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('status')).getText()).toMatch('Current Filter:');

        //input('query').enter('nexus');

        //queryInput.clear();
        //queryInput.sendKeys('nexus');

        //expect(element('#status').text()).toMatch(/Current filter: nexus\s*$/);
        //expect(ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('status')).getText()).toMatch('^\Current Filter:.');

        //alternative version of the last assertion that tests just the value of the binding
        //using('#status').expect(binding('query')).toBe('nexus');
    });
```

the first test, search box, works great.
the second test, status, does not pass because the last value entered in queryInput is carried over to the second test, and the queryInput.clear() does not work.
However, in the second test, if i make a call queryInput.sendKeys("something"), "something" will display. 
If I take out the clear() in the second test, I'll see "motorolasomething".
So, while it seems the clear() is working, my test is not passing if I just have clear() in the second test, when i run the second test, I will see "motorola", even when clear() is called prior to the second test.

I'm wondering why the clear() is not clearing in the second test when I do not have a sendKeys() after it.

Comment: Plz ignore, I see the problem. The clear() is working, but the status div needs to be updated on the page with another method after clear() is called

Answer (score 41):

The Documentation of clear() says the following:

> [ !webdriver.promise.Promise ] **clear**( )
>
> Schedules a command to clear
>   the {@code value} of this element. This command has no effect if the
>   underlying DOM element is neither a text INPUT element nor a TEXTAREA
>   element.
>
> **Returns**: A promise that will be resolved when the element has
>   been cleared.

so in order to get clear to do what you want, you have to work with the promise that it returns! to do so you have to use `then()`

here is how it works:

```
queryInput.clear().then(function() {
    queryInput.sendKeys('motorola');
})
```

so `clear()` returns you a promise to clear the input and `then()` tells the promise what to do as soon as the input is cleared.

Comment: You can also chain these promises to save some space:  queryInput.clear().sendKeys('motorola').sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);

Comment: No you cannot chain them. This doesn't resolve the promise of clear. You have to use `.then()`

Answer (score 6):

```
await element.sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, 'a'));

await element.sendKeys(Key.DELETE);
```

Comment: Does this solution work on other platforms? (Like macOS)

Comment: Does not work for me. Here is a workaround for cross-platform and/or stubborn cases: stackoverflow.com/a/65477389/3021889 (eg. auto-formatted fields or protractor/OS incompatibilities)

Comment: Can confirm this won't work in macOS, so you need to keep that in mind

Answer (score 4):

`Clear().then(..)` doesn't work for me.

So this is my work around:

```
queryInput.sendKeys(protrator.Key.chord(protrator.Key.CONTROL, 'a'));
queryInput.sendKeys('nexus')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine promisses into a chain:

`queryInput.clear().sendKeys('nexus');`

Comment: these aren't promises, a promise really only has a `then()` method. But I upvoted this because it works because these are simply chained methods on the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Using PageObject pattern and async/await, I have such code that works:

```
async clearForm() {
    await this.nameInput.clear();
    await this.descriptionInput.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
         click(`${fieldId}`).then(() => {
                        yourElement.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "a")).then(() => {
                            yourElement.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
                            yourElement.clear();
}
```