# Protractor functional test does not update ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor, angular-material, jasmine2.0

So in my basic angular app, I have a login form :

```
<form layout="column" class="form">
  <md-input-container>
    <label for="email" translate>login.email</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" ng-model="login.user.email" />
    <span ng-bind="login.user.email"></span>
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container>
    <label for="password" translate>login.password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" ng-model="login.user.password" />
    <span ng-bind="login.user.password"></span>
  </md-input-container>
  <md-button class="hbd-primary"  ng-click="login.authenticate()" id="submit-button">
    <span translate>login.connection</span>
  </md-button>
</form>
```

I am currently writing functional tests with protractor and jasmine. Here is my login test :

```
it('should fail login with bogus credentials', function() {
  page.emailInput.clear().then(function() {
    page.emailInput.sendKeys('supermerchant@bogus.com');
  });
  expect(page.emailInput.getAttribute('value')).toBe('supermerchant@bogus.com');
  page.passwordInput.clear().then(function() {
    return page.passwordInput.sendKeys('boguspass');
  })
  .then(function() {
    expect(page.passwordInput.getAttribute('value')).toBe('boguspass');
    return page.submitButton.click();
  })
  .then(function() {
    expect(page.alert.element(by.id("login-alert-text")).getText())
      .toBe('Email ou mot de passe invalide');
  });
});
```

My problem is with the sendKeys() method, even if it writes the email and password correctly (visually it is in the inputs), when it triggers login function I noticed something weird with the request params : the fields email and password of my object user are empty eg "". But when I check the inputs 'value' attribute, it is correctly filled eg "supermerchant@bogus.com" & "boguspass".

So I searched a lot but found nothing so far, I have no idea where the issue could be...

Any leads would be very appreciated !

**EDIT**: additional code from controller and service.

**Login controller**

```
var vm = this;
vm.errors = '';
vm.user = {email: 'a', password: 'a', remember: true};
/**
*
* Log the user in.
*
**/
function authenticate() {
  vm.errors = '';
  retrieveToken(vm.user);
};

/**
*
* Get the jwt token. Change state depending on status.
*
**/
function retrieveToken(user) {
  authService.login(user)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      saveToken(data.token);
      $state.go('employee');
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      vm.errors = 'Email ou mot de passe invalide';
    });
};

/**
*
* Store the authenticated user.
*
**/
function saveToken(dataToken) {
  var token = jwtHelper.decodeToken(dataToken);
  var user = {
    id: token.id,
    firstName: token.firstName,
    lastName: token.lastName,
    roles: token.roles,
    token: dataToken
  };
  authService.setAuthentication(true, user);
};
```

**authService**

```
function auth($injector, constants) {
  var _authenticated = false;
  var _user = null;
  var service = {
    login: login,
    isAuthenticated: isAuth,
    setAuthentication: setAuth,
    getToken: getToken
  };

  /**
  *
  * Get the user authentication jwt.
  *
  **/
  function login(user) {
    return $injector.get('$http')
      .post(constants.baseApiUrl + 'authentication/login', user);
  };

  /**
  *
  * Return a boolean to check if user is connected to app.
  *
  **/
  function isAuth() {
    return _authenticated;
  };

  /**
  *
  * Set the current user authentication.
  *
  **/
  function setAuth(auth, user) {
    if (auth) {
      _authenticated = true;
      _user = user;
    }
    else if (auth === false) {
      _authenticated = false;
      _user = null;
    }
  };
```

**EDIT2**: When I set the fields email and password to anything, those values do not change when authenticating, even with the clear and sendKeys. But visually, the inputs are cleared and filled correctly. So I suspect the issue to be a data binding one. Maybe the two way binding is broken in some way.

**EDIT3**: Ok so under every inputs I added a span with a ng-binding to email and password model. When sendKeys and clear are used, the spans value do not change (eg 'a'). So there is a data binding issue ! Value change when I manually delete a character from the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hours and hours, I got the solution.

When launching functional tests, I was using browser Sync and opened another browser to check if everything was ok.

Somewhat, after using browser sync option `open: false` and letting phantomjs doing it's magic, everything work. Not sure why it was an issue but it is now resolved !

Answer (score 0):

In our tests, we use clear and sendKeys but on separate calls.

So for your case, try:

```
page.emailInput.clear();
page.emailInput.sendKeys('supermerchant@bogus.com');
```

Another approach - [Protractor clear() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966240/protractor-clear-not-working)

Comment: Thanks but already tried. EDIT: IMO it is an angular issue since model is empty but not the input value.

Comment: So is the test actually passing?

Comment: Yes because it sends user:{password: "", email: ""} to the login, which then fails as expected.

Comment: Can you share your controller code for `login.authenticate()`

Comment: So does this login code all work fine running locally in the browser. Is it only when running the tests you see the issue?

Comment: Yes, exactly ! It only fails on tests because of the empty fields.

Comment: I notice you are using `vm.user` in your controller, so I guess you are using controllerAs syntax? Your ng-model bindings are referencing a login scope property object, so how is `login` linking to `vm.user`?

Comment: Yes I am using an ng-controller="Login as login" in a parent of the form.

Comment: Ok well I'm out of ideas on this! I am using protractor and have login tests very similar to yours, using ng-model, etc. One thing that jumps out as strange to me with your test is your `browser.wait` call for the button to be clickable - why are you needing to do this?

Comment: I am using this to be sure that the button and the app are loaded before, but I will try without. Yeah I have no clue too, maybe angular binding is broken for this test, maybe I need jasmine2, I don't know... EDIT: this issue appears on every browser I try. Chrome, FF, phantomJs...

Comment: I added some edition, tldr there is a data binding issue.

Comment: Hmm ok, I actually am using Jasmine 2