# Typescript error: Property 'clear' or 'send' does not exist on type 'unknown' in protractor

Tags: node.js, typescript, jasmine, protractor

Unable to use clear and sendKeys in protractor using typescript. Am I missing any dependencies because even click is throwing an error?

I tried different solutions from [Protractor clear() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966240/protractor-clear-not-working) 
but none seems to be working

```
 async setEmail(username: String) {
        let emailField = await browser.wait(until.presenceOf(element(by.css("#username"))), DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_SECONDS * 1000, 'Email field never appeared.');
     /* await emailField.clear().then(()=>{
           emailField.sendKeys(username);
       });*/
    emailField.clear();
    emailField.sendKeys(username);
       /* await emailField.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'a'));
        await emailField.sendKeys(username);*/
    }
```

E/launcher - Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
e2e/common/pageObjects/loginLogoutWorkflow/LoginPageEntities.ts(64,16): error TS2339: Property 'clear' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
e2e/common/pageObjects/loginLogoutWorkflow/LoginPageEntities.ts(65,17): error TS2339: Property 'sendKeys' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

Comment: I haven't used protractor but it looks like you need to make sure `emailField` is of the correct type. What type of object does `browser.wait()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try below code snippet as well.

```
async setEmail(username: String) {

var EC = browser.ExpectedConditions;
let emailField = element(by.css("#username"));


await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(emailField),10000);

await emailField.clear();
await emailField.sendKeys(username);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
async setEmail(username: String) {
  let emailField = element(by.css("#username"));
  await browser.wait(
    protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(emailField), 
    DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_SECONDS * 1000, 
    'Email field never appeared.'
  );
  await emailField.clear();
  await emailField.sendKeys(username);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing my mistake!!! It worked. I really appreciate your help. Since I am a newbie with protractor with typescript. @Sergey Pleshakov can you please suggest where I can find good tutorials online for reference?

Comment: honestly, the best tutorial I saw was a quality code in a company I joined :) Basically everything I learned was from looking at someone else's code. All tutorials online are very basic @PaneeS

Comment: I completely agree with you. I am facing challenge to build a customized framework without much knowledge. But answers on stackover flow is really helping me a lot. Thanks